# Eclipse EE Kepler Spring MVC unable to locate views in .html/.jsp

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm new to **Spring MVC**. I'm trying out simple projects like Hello World. 
I originally created a Hello World using **IntelliJ IDEA** IDE which worked just fine. However, when I tried **Eclipse EE IDE**, it returned a `404` message

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name> <!-- spring-dispatcher is the file named spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml -->
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcproject" />

    <!-- HandlerMapping class -->
    <!--  There are plenty of handler mapping classes, this is just an example of one of the classes available -->
    <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />



    <!-- defines the location or path where to look for views and what file extension to look for -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />

        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </bean>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.springmvcproject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;



@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld(){

        return "hellopage";
    }
}
```

**hellopage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4> This is the hello page (HelloPage.jsp)</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't see any reasons why it will not display the contents of the `hellopage.jsp` when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/hello`

Here's the screenshot of the folder structure. There are no warnings or error.

[image]

I don't know if I just missed something here or if Eclipse is requiring something else.

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Comment: is this project built using maven?

Comment: @kuhajeyan I dont remember creating the project as Maven project in Eclipse. I just pasted the jar files of spring 4.3.3 in the lib folder of the project.